# SSHFS over a jumphost

Tags: ssh, sshfs, fuse

I have 3 computers. A, B, and C.

A is the one I'm on now. B is a jumphost that I can SSH through from A to get to computer C using `ssh -t B_host ssh C_host`.

What I'd like to do is mount C's file system to A through an SSHFS command but a brief look at the man pages didn't show any linking commands.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9):

This can also be accomplished directly on the command-line if needed via:

```
sshfs -o ssh_command="ssh -J B_host" C_host:/<path> <mountpoint>
```

Thanks to [this Unix & Linux answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495851/432493) for the info.  However, this ServerFault question is currently the top Google result for *sshfs jumphost*, so copying the info over here as well to hopefully save some future searchers some time.

Comment: `sshfs -o ProxyJump=B_host C_host:/<path> <mountpoint>` 

would be more direct.

Answer (score 8):

A simpler version of the mechanism mentioned in the older answer has since been released.  Still using ~/.ssh/config, this will accomplish the same w/ simpler syntax:

```
Host <host alias>
    User <host_username>
    HostName <host_name>
    ProxyJump [user@]<jump host>[:port]
```

Answer (score 7):

Working off a similar SFTP/SCP based question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/6iqpgv/how_to_scp_or_sftp_from_laptop_to_server_through/) you have to modify your SSH Config file as follows (located `~/.ssh/config`)

```
    Host B
        HostName <B_host>
        User <B_user>
        ForwardAgent yes

    Host C
        User <C_user>
        HostName <C_host>
        ProxyCommand ssh B -W %h:%p
```

And then it 'just works' when you run the following from A:

```
 sshfs hostC:/<path to mount on C> <path to mount on A>
```

Brilliant!

Comment: Brilliant indeed! Thanks for this, it's exactly what I needed. I don't know why the downvotes. Google brought me here and this fixed my problem - it's a win for me!